# Callback/promises for $cordovaDialogs in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

`$cordovaDialogs` itself has a promises as follow:

```
$cordovaDialog.alert('message', 'title', 'OK').then(function() {
    $state.go('app.nextPage');
});
```

It working perfectly fine if i use directly, but now I am trying to encapsulate it into a function as follow:

```
app.factory('AppCommon', function ($cordovaDialogs) {

    var alert = function(message, title, confirmButton) {
        $cordovaDialogs.alert(message, title, confirmButton)
    }

    return {
        alert: alert
    }
});
```

Now I am trying to use it this way but it fails. What can i do to make `$state.go` to execute only if the alert box is confirmed?

```
AppCommon.alert('message', 'title', 'OK').then(function() {
    $state.go('app.nextPage');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the promise you are trying to do `.then` on from `alert()` function. Since `$cordovaDialogs.alert()` returns a promise, you need to return it.

```
app.factory('AppCommon', function ($cordovaDialogs) {

  var alert = function(message, title, confirmButton) {
    return $cordovaDialogs.alert(message, title, confirmButton)
  }

  return {
    alert: alert
  }
});
```